# Can I influence the auto generated schema when importing a firestore export into Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore

I am running regular imports from Firestore into BigQuery using the Google Cloud UI. One of my collections has data that has optional fields and often these are not available to query in BigQuery.

I presume that the auto schema generation takes a sample from the firestore data to generate a schema.

The documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#auto-detect says "the table schema is automatically retrieved from the self-describing source data."

Is there any way to add hints to the auto generation and include the optional fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but it's not available via the web UI but available via CLI or API

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#cloud_firestore_options